Suppose that $G$ is a finite subgroup of ${\rm SO}(3)$. Is there a *smooth* self-map of ${\bf R}^3$ whose fibers are precisely the orbits of $G$?
$\newcommand\R{\mathbf R}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\newcommand\C{\mathbf C}$The question is motivated by the theory of orbifolds. If $\mathcal O$ is an orientable $3$-orbifold (without boundary), an affirmative answer to the question would give a smooth manifold structure on the underlying space $X_{\mathcal O}$ with the property that all orbifold charts, regarded as maps from open subsets of $\R^3$ to $X_{\mathcal O}$, are smooth.
If one replaces $\SO(3)$ and $\R^3$ by $\SO(2)$ and $\R^2$, the answer is affirmative and easy: $G$ must be cyclic, and if we identify $\R^2$ with the field $\C$ of complex numbers, a generator acts by $z\mapsto\exp(2\pi i/n)z$ for some $n$. The required map is then $z\mapsto z^n$. This also gives an affirmative answer in the three-dimensional setting if one assumes $G$ is cyclic: if we identify $\R^3$ with $\C\times\R$, we may assume after conjugation that the generator acts by $(z,t)\mapsto(\exp(2\pi i/n)z,t)$ for some $n$. The required map is then $(z,t)\mapsto (z^n,t) $.
The answer is also affirmative if one asks for a continuous map instead of a smooth one. It follows by radial extension from the fact that the quotient of $S^2$ by a finite group, which acts by orientation-preserving homeomorphisms, is homeomorphic to $S^2$. This can even be used to get a continuous map having the desired property, and smooth except at the origin.
The interesting case is the one in which $G$ is non-cyclic, which means it is a spherical triangle group. It can be as "simple" as a dihedral group of arbitrary finite order, or as "complicated" as the alternating  group on five letters.

It is of course clear what you mean, but I like the choice of wording that it can be as simple as a non-simple group, or as complicated as a simple group.

In the 2-dimensional case, you get an analytic map, while the smoothing technique makes the smooth map non-analytic at zero, so a follow-up question would be whether the self-map can be arranged to be analytic.

One might even ask about a polynomial map. One could indeed wonder whether the algebra of $G$-invariant polynomials is indeed a polynomial algebra.

@YCor It's not a polynomial algebra, by the Chevalley-Shepard-Todd theorem. I was also thinking about whether polynomials could work. Given the OP's motivation, one should probably add the condition that the map should be surjective. For example, if one takes the standard action of $S_3$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (so using matrices in $O(3)$, not $SO(3)$), then the orbits are the fibers of the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x+y+z, xy+xz+yz, xyz)$, but the image of this map is not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I suspect something similar can happen with $SO(3)$ matrices.

@DavidESpeyer thanks. In dim. 3, there's something with orientation-reversing matrices of finite order that the (orbifold) quotient is not smooth, even topologically, while they are for orientation-preserving ones (since the fixed-point-set has codimension 2).

@LSpice Yes. "The Fischer-Griess monster? Actually, it's all very simple..."

YCor: Yes, if the group has order $2$ and is generated by $-I$, then the underlying space of the quotient will be the open cone on the real projective plane, so not a topological manifold.

Here is a standard trick: Let $f: S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ be a smooth map. We would like to extend it "radially" to a smooth map $F: \mathbb R^{n}\to \mathbb R^{n}$ such that if $f$ is $\rho$-equivariant, so is $F$, where, $G< O(n)$ and $\rho: G\to O(n)$ is a representation (in your case, trivial representation). For $x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ set $r:=|x|$ and $\bar x:= x/r$. Then for $x\in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$define
$$
F(x)= e^{-1/r} f(\bar x), F(0)=0.
$$
Clearly, $F$ is again $\rho$-equivariant. One verifies that $F$ is smooth: This is clear away from the origin and at the origin follows from vanishing of derivatives of all orders of the function $r\mapsto \exp(-1/r), r> 0$, at $r= 0$.
One uses the same argument to show that for every Milnor's exotic  sphere $\Sigma^7$ there is a smooth homeomorphism $\Sigma^7\to S^7$.
Edit. Even though you already know how to construct the required smooth map $f: S^2\to S^2$ given a finite subgroup $G< SO(3)$, here is how I would do this. Let $\Sigma\subset S^2$ denote the complement to the set of fixed points of nontrivial elements of $G$ in $S^2$. The group $G$ acts freely (properly) and isometrically on $\Sigma$ (preserving the restriction of the standard Riemannian metric on $S^2$), hence, the quotient $\Sigma':=\Sigma/G$ has a Riemannian metric with respect to which the projection $\pi: \Sigma\to  \Sigma'$ is a local isometry. Regarding $\Sigma'$ as a Riemann surface (with respect to the above Riemannian structure) and using the uniformization theorem, find a holomorphic embedding $h: \Sigma'\to S^2$. Riemann extension theorem implies that $h\circ \pi: \Sigma\to S^2$ extends to a holomorphic map $f: S^2\to S^2$. From the construction, it is clear that $f(x)=f(y)$ if and only if $Gx=Gy$. Thus, $f$ is the required smooth map $S^2\to S^2$. Now, apply the above extension construction and get a smooth map
$$
F: \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3
$$
which also has the property $F(x)=F(y)\iff Gx=Gy$. This gives a positive answer to your question.

You're stating no conclusion, so it takes time to figure out what's going on. Am I correct that given the fact stated by the OP ($S^2$ modulo orientation-preserving finite group is still $S^2$, in the smooth category), your argument yields the conclusion?

@YCor: Right. Peter stated that he already knows how to find the required smooth map of $S^2$. But I will add a proof of this for completeness.

OK. I also mean that it's useful if you say at the beginning that you're positively answering the question.

@MoisheKohan, many thanks. This certainly answers my question. It's not the kind of answer that I expected, but the fact that it's of an unexpected kind is  valuable: it made me realize that the required map may be very far from being canonical. This points up an issue about my original question. The affirmative answer to my "title" question does show that there are local charts for $X_{\mathcal O}$ with the property that I stated, but without some kind of canonicality it is not clear why the transition maps for $X_{\mathcal O}$ should be smooth.  See my comment for David E. Speyer below.

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$I have been thinking about whether we could find a polynomial map with these properties. The answer is yes in every case except possibly one: I have checked the case of the cyclic groups, the dihedral groups, the rotational symmetries of the tetrahedron, and the rotational symmetries of the cube/octahedron. I have not been able to figure out whether such a polynomial map exists for the icosahedron/dodecahedron.
As a reminder, this is the full list of finite subgroups of $SO(3)$.
The cyclic case: Let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$. Identify $\RR^3$ with $\CC \times \RR$ and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Then $C_n$ acts on $\CC \times \RR$ by maps of the form $(w, t) \mapsto (\zeta^k w, t)$. So the map $(w,t) \mapsto (w^n, t)$ is a polynomial map whose fibers are the orbits of the cyclic group. Note that $\text{Re}((x+iy)^n)$, $\text{Im}((x+iy)^n)$ do NOT generate the ring of $C_n$-invariants inside $\RR[x,y]$: The polynomial $x^2+y^2$ is $C_n$-invariant, but not in the ring generated by $\text{Re}((x+iy)^n)$, $\text{Im}((x+iy)^n)$ for $n>2$.
The dihedral case: Let $D_n = C_n \rtimes C_2$.
Again, identify $\RR^3$ with $\CC \times \RR$ and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. In the dihedral action, the subgroup $C_n$ acts by $(w, t) \mapsto (\zeta^k w, t)$ and the nontrivial element of $C_2$ acts by $(w, t) \mapsto (\overline{w}, -t)$.
Put $w' = w^n$, so $w'$ and $t$ are invariant for the subgroup $C_n$ of $D_n$. Then $D_n/C_n$ acts by $(w', t) \mapsto (\overline{w'}, -t)$. Write $w' = x'+iy'$. Then the action of $D_n/C_n$ on $(x', y', t)$ is by $(x', y', t) \mapsto (x', -y', -t)$. We can think of this as a $C_2$ action as in the cyclic case, so we can compose the map $(x,y,t) \to (x', y', t)$ with the quotient by $C_2$ from the cyclic case to get a polynomial map whose fibers are the $D_n$-orbits. Explicitly, the three polynomials are
$${\Big(} \text{Re}{\big(}(x+iy)^n{\big)},\ \text{Re}{\big(}(\text{Im}((x+iy)^n) + i t)^2{\big)},\ \text{Im}{\big(}(\text{Im}((x+iy)^n) + i t)^2{\big)}{\Big)}.$$
The Klein $4$-group, again Let $K$ be the Klein $4$-group $C_2 \times C_2$, acting by the diagonal $\pm 1$ matrices with determinant $1$. This is the case $n=2$ of the previous example, so we already have a solution in this case: Explicitly, the above computation gives $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x^2-y^2, 4 x^2 y^2 - z^2, 2 xyz)$ as a solution. However, we want a different solution to use as a building block for the tetrahedral and cubical cases. Thus, the purpose of this section is to verify that
$$(x,y,z) \mapsto (x^2-y^2, y^2-z^2, xyz)$$
also works. It is clear that these polynomials are $K$-invariant, so what remains to show is that, given a triples of real numbers $(a,b,t)$, the set of real solutions to $x^2-y^2 = a$, $y^2-z^2 = b$, $xyz=t$ is precisely one $K$-orbit.
First of all, negating all of $(x,y,z)$ preserves $x^2-y^2$ and $y^2-z^2$, while negating $xyz$, so we may as well assume that $t \geq 0$. At which point, it is equivalent to show that there is a unique solution for $(x,y,z) \in \RR_{\geq 0}^3$. Also, permuting $(x,y,z)$ gives a linear action of $S_3$ on $a$ and $b$, with $x^2 \geq y^2 \geq z^2$ corresponding to $a$, $b \geq 0$. So we can assume that $a$, $b \geq 0$, and then we must show that there is a unique solution with $x \geq y \geq z \geq 0$.
The equations $x^2-y^2=a$ and $y^2 - z^2 = b$ are solved by taking $x = \sqrt{z^2+a+b}$, $y = \sqrt{z^2+b}$. The remaining equation is $t = \sqrt{z^2+a+b} \cdot \sqrt{z^2+b} \cdot z$. As $z$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$, the function $\sqrt{z^2+a+b} \cdot \sqrt{z^2+b} \cdot z$ increases monotonically from $0$ to $\infty$. So, for each $t \in [0, \infty)$, there is a unique $z$ with $t = \sqrt{z^2+a+b} \cdot \sqrt{z^2+b} \cdot z$, and then $(\sqrt{z^2+a+b},\ \sqrt{z^2+b}\ z)$ is the unique solution with $x \geq y \geq z \geq 0$ that we seek.
Before proceeding, it is convenient to make a linear change of coordinates in the above solution: Put
$$c = x^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} y^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} z^2 = a + \tfrac{1}{2} b \ \text{and}\  d = \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} y^2 - \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} z^2  = \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} b.$$
So $(c,d,t)$ is a linear change of coordinates away from $(a,b,t)$, and thus $(x,y,z) \mapsto (c,d,t)$ also has fibers equal to the orbits of $K$.
The tetrahedral group We now consider the group of symmetries of the tetrahedron, which can be written as $K \rtimes C_3$, where $C_3$ acts by cyclic permutation matrices. The reason that we worked so hard to build a new quotient by $K$ in the previous example is that the ring $\RR[a,b,t] = \RR[x^2-y^2, y^2-z^2, xyz]$ inherits an action of $C_3$. (In contrast, our general dihedral group solution gave us a different subring, $\RR[x^2-y^2, 4 x^2 y^2 - z^2, 2 xyz]$, which is not taken to itself under cyclic permutations of the variables.)
Explicitly, the action of $C_3$ fixes $t=xyz$ and acts linearly on $\RR a + \RR b$. In the linear change of coordinates $\RR a + \RR b = \RR c + \RR d$, this is the cyclic action of $C_3$ that we discussed above. So $(\text{Re}((c+id)^3),\ \text{Im}((c+id)^3),\ t)$ is a triple of polynomials as required.
The cubical case This example is like the previous one; the group is $K \rtimes S_3$, where the even permutations in $S_3$ act by permutation matrices and the odd permutations act by negations of the corresponding permutation matrix. (For example, $(x,y,z) \mapsto (-x, -z, -y)$. Note that this example preserves $c$ and negates $d$ and $t$.) As before, we get an action of $S_3$ on the ring $\RR[c,d,t]$, which is the dihedral action of $S_3$ that we discussed above. So, composing our map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (c,d,t)$ with the dihedral quotient by $S_3$, we get the desired map.
I don't know how to handle the icosahedral case. Since the group in question is $A_5$, which is simple, we can't hope to build up the solution in steps, as we did in the previous solvable cases.

Many thanks. In the back of my mind I had been imagining using polynomial maps. I believe the issue that you pointed out in connection with the cyclic case, that the coordinate functions do not generate the full ring of polynomial invariants, is related to the issue about smoothness of the transition maps that I mentioned in my comment above on Moishe Kohan's answer. You've given me a lot to think about.
By the way, the issue of surjectivity, which you had mentioned in an earlier comment, doesn't seem crucial to me.
